# Can USB devices be used with X11 over the network?

Tags: x11, usb, remote

I'm considering running an X11 client on an existing server, and then having a thin 'client' (X11 server) on a Raspberry Pi or similar, as a development environment / general computing.

However, occasionally I need to plug in a USB scanner (or flash drive, etc.). Can they be shared cleanly over X, or would the only way be something like [saned](https://linux.die.net/man/8/saned) (or samba, etc.)?

I can ssh from client to server, but I can't/don't want to allow the server to access services like that on the 'client'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after, but perhaps `usbip` can help. It allows use of a usb device over a network.

Comment: @meuh Thanks, that's the sort of thing I meant by using something like saned/samba (though a more general and better looking solution). Due to the network though, I can't have the remote machine (X11 client) accessing services on the local one. I was hoping for 'USB over X' so that it's all local -> remote.

Comment: You can forward the usbip port over ssh just as you can forward X11. It's not clear what you're after, though with your "not something like saned/samba" -- since they're so dfferent beasts, everything in this world is "something like saned/samba" ;-)

Comment: "You can forward the usbip port over ssh just as you can forward X11." that sounds like the answer, so run `usbip` and 'remote forward' the correct port to the X11 client; then start the X11 session and attach `usbip` to the local port. Makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) USB devices can't be forwarded by X11.

2) USB devices can be used over the network e.g. by [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/).

3) There are various ways to use specific devices, like scanners, printers, or storage, over the network.

4) Your description looks like you are unclear on the terms "X11 server" and "X11 client". The X11 server usually runs on the machine that is connected to the display hardware, and the mouse and keyboard etc. X11 is a network protocol, so you can run the X11 client anywhere. However, that doesn't work well with modern applications, which expect to be able to use hardware acceleration on the machine they are running on, and therefore only work well if the X11 client and the X11 server run on the same machine.

5) If you want some permanent setup, you shouldn't need `ssh`.

As I don't understand your description well (what is the "existing server"? A desktop PC? Do you want to use the RaspPi as a thin client (i.e., connect it to a monitor, and run an X11 server on it)? Or as a "general computing device" (it's not that powerful)), so I can't really give recommendations about the best way to setup things.

Comment: Per @mosvy's comment on OP, that sounds like the way to go, thanks. Re 4 - no, understood, that's why I was careful to say that the 'thin client' was the 'X11 server'. Not sure what you mean by ssh not needed for permanent setup? I use it all the time for many 'permanent' things.

Comment: I meant that if you want to use the RaspPi as a sort of "X terminal" (that's what a "thin client" is), you install the X11 server on the RaspPi, enable networking (`-tcplisten`), set up a display manager on the "main PC" to connect to the RaspPi, and then you can just login to the RaspPi and work "on" the main PC. No `ssh` involved. You may want to have a look at [virtualgl](https://www.virtualgl.org/About/Introduction) or something similar for that setup. If you want to plug USB devices into the RaspPi, I'd set up `usbip` so they appear on the desktop PC.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer all of your questions, but perhaps this will be of some use:

I use a Macbook mostly, and I also have a Raspberry Pi (RPi) which I operate in "headless" mode (i.e. no monitor or keyboard connected). I occasionally do Python development for the RPi, and in some instances it's useful to do code development with [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) in the *target* environment. I have [installed the XQuartz app](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/XQuartzInstall.md) on my Mac to enable that. I use X forwarding in SSH for this; it's very easy to set up and use:

Launch XQuartz, and in its terminal window, enter:

```bsh
$ ssh -Y pi@raspberrypi3b.local  
$ idle3 &
```

This should open a new X window with `idle3` from the RPi; it may look like this:

[image: idle3 in Xalso]

With respect to your USB drives and devices: I have a USB drive and a "thumb drive" plugged into my RPi, and I access those (mostly) from the command line in SSH in the "usual way". I'm not currently using any graphical apps or file manager under X, so I can't comment on that. If you need the GUI on RPi, I'm under the impression that most people do that using [`vnc`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/).

Comment: Thanks, though I'm talking about the USB devices on the other side - plugged into the laptop in your example, and then used from the session on the Pi.